# Improving the Sizing in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on a project that uses Bootstrap 3.1. One of the things I don't like about Bootstrap is that it is pixel based. I would really like to use REMs. I know Zurb Foundation uses REMs. However, it doesn't have all of the stuff I need. Plus, I'm not as familiar with it.

Is there any way to use REMs instead of Pixels in Bootstrap? If so, how?

Comment: I'm sorry, Bootstrap source code (.less files) uses pixels, so there is no easy way of changing that.
But do try out Foundation, it's more progressive in many ways, while being more simplistic (IMO). The correct setup with Compass is a bit of a chore, but once you get it going, it works very well.

Comment: I really enjoy Foundation. Not a fan of SASS/Compass though. The whole Ruby thing is a turn-off. Plus, the community support around Bootstrap is hard to beat.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in this thread here [Why does Twitter Bootstrap Use Pixels for Font Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999267/why-does-twitter-bootstrap-use-pixels-for-font-size) Jasny - Arnold Daniels posts a solution to convert Bootstrap to EMs or REMs. I have not actually tried it myself, but I believe this is the solution you seek.