# bootstrap: Font-sizes in px, has em / rem not in use any more?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-size

I currently use bootstrap on a site I am designing. Previously I always used EMs for fonts and I have just learned about the new REM. Understanding this now, I notice in bootstrap no font-sizes are declared as EM or REM.

Increasing the font size of the browser seems to not give any effect to the bootstrap site as the base font seems to be set in PX and not at a percentage.

Should we now just use PX for fonts as well as images ?

I am a little confused which direction to take.

PX for fonts, which always used to be NOT recommended but now looking how bootstrap is setup, I don't see what benefit the REM / EMs have over anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is apparently going to use rem: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4#new-unit-rems-for-typography

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Twitter Bootstrap Use Pixels for Font Size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999267/why-does-twitter-bootstrap-use-pixels-for-font-size)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ussualy use PX for html element, and EM for other elements, because if I want to change font-size of all elements of document, I only need to change font-size of html